# jinja2 show comma separated list on several lines

Tags: jinja2

I would like to show comma separated list on multiple lines by limited groups. For example by groups of 3 elements:

```
['111', '222', '333', '444', '555', '666', '777']
```

should be:

```
111, 222, 333,
444, 555, 666,
777
```

In jinja2 there is a 'join' filter which shows comma separated list.
There is a 'batch' filter.
But I could not make them work as I would like.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting in to sublist as you said `batch`, and then use `join`:

```
list = ['111', '222', '333', '444', '555', '666', '777']

{% for items in list|batch(3) %}
    {{ items|join(",") }}
{%endfor%}
```

Comment: You have missed commas at the end of lines.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally made it.

```
items=['111', '222', '333', '444', '555', '666', '777']

{% for batch_items in items|batch(3) %}{{ batch_items | join(', ') }}{% if not loop.last %},
{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```